# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context in Swift3

Tags: swift, swift3, swift2

I am getting a 'Type of expression is ambiguous without more context ' on this part of code from a project I am trying to upgrade to latest Swift version. I can't seem to figure it out. I tried different things but can't get it to work.

The problem is on the syntax of this line:

```
var sec = Int64(0.001 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
let time = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(sec) <---- Error here   
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: time)
```

The compiler is pointing out the addition(+) of

> DsipatchTime.now()

to the

> .seconds(sec)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`DispatchTimeInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchtimeinterval) has a `case .seconds(Int)`, so you cannot 
create it from an `Int64`.

Also `Int64(0.001 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))` 
is `1000000`, which is probably *not* the time in seconds that
you want to wait (that would be approximately 277 hours).

You can create a dispatch time interval with fractional seconds
using the `.milli/micro/nanoseconds` cases, e.g.:

```
let milliseconds = 1
let time = DispatchTime.now() + .milliseconds(milliseconds)
```

Or simply by adding a `Double` specifying the amount in seconds:

```
let sec = 0.001
let time = DispatchTime.now() + sec
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

`var sec = Int64(0.001 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))`

to

`var sec = Int(0.001 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))`

This is needed because `DispatchTimeInterval` expects an `Int`.